# View does behave differently in parent view than in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made a view in SwiftUI, that gets wrapped inside a Button in a other view.

```
struct BuySubscriptionView: View {
    var subscriptionText: String = "Monthly Subscription"
    var amountText: String = "2.99 € / Month"
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Text(subscriptionText)
                .bold()
                    .fixedSize()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                Text("Access to all exercises")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
            }.padding(.vertical)
            VStack(alignment:.trailing) {
                Text("Subscribe")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.baseDark)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .padding(1)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                Text(amountText).bold()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .padding(.top)
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
        .padding()
            .background(Color.baseDark)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .padding(1)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

I wrap it inside a button. When I use it in the PreviewProvider everything gets generated correctly:

```
static var previews: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 70) {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {

                }, label: {
                    BuySubscriptionView(subscriptionText: "Monthly Subscription", amountText: "29.99€/month").frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9, height: geometry.size.width * 0.2, alignment: .center)
                })
                Button(action: {

                }, label: {
                    BuySubscriptionView().frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9, height: geometry.size.width * 0.2, alignment: .center)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

But when implementing it in my app, they do not have the same size anymore

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Hello " + self.userName + "!" ).font(.title)
                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
                self.premiumTextView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.6)
                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
                Group {
                    if !self.isPremium {
                        VStack(alignment: .center,spacing: 70) {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.buyPremium()
                            }, label: {
                                BuySubscriptionView()
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9, height: geometry.size.width * 0.2, alignment: .center)
                            })
                            Button(action: {
                                self.buyPremium()
                            }, label: {
                                BuySubscriptionView(subscriptionText: "Yearly Subscription", amountText: "29.99 € / Year")
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9, height: geometry.size.width * 0.2, alignment: .center)
                            })
                        }

                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
                LogInOutButton(action: {
                    self.logOut()
                }, title: "Log out", width: geometry.size.width * 0.7)
            }
        }
    }
```

And it looks like that:

[image]

Why does it behave like that? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is effect of tightening for content - your "Yearly..." label is shorter, so resulting view is smaller. Please find below slightly corrected your label view.

```
struct BuySubscriptionView: View {
    var subscriptionText: String = "Monthly Subscription"
    var amountText: String = "2.99 € / Month"
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Text(subscriptionText)
                .bold()
                    .fixedSize()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                Text("Access to all exercises")
                .fixedSize()                                     // << here!
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
            }.padding(.vertical)
            Spacer()                                             // << here!
            VStack(alignment:.trailing) {
                Text("Subscribe")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .padding(1)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                Text(amountText).bold()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .padding(.top)
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
        .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .padding(1)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Result: (with substituted custom colours)

[image: demo]

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2